# Play Framework: How to implement REST API for File Upload

Tags: javascript, scala, rest, file-upload, playframework

I'm developing a REST API with Play 2 and I'm wondering how to implement file upload functionality.

I've read the [official Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFileUpload) but it just provides a `multipart/form-data` example, while my backend does not provide any form... it just consists of a REST API to be invoked by a JavaScript client or whatever else.

That said, what's the correct way to implement such an API? Should I implement a `PartHandler` and then still use the `mutipartFormData` parser? How should I pass the file content to the API? Is there any exhaustive example on this topic?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thank you all for your suggestions... here below is how I solved my issue:

```
object Files extends Controller {

  def upload = SecuredAction[Files.type]("upload").async(parse.multipartFormData(partHandler)) { implicit request =>
    future { request.body.files.head.ref match {
      case Some((data, fileName, contentType)) => Ok(success(Json.obj("fileName" -> fileName)))
      case _ => BadRequest
    }}.recover { case e =>
     InternalServerError(error(errorProcessingRequest(e.getMessage)))
    }
  }

  ...

  private def partHandler = {
    parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case parse.Multipart.FileInfo(partName, fileName, contentType) =>
        Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], ByteArrayOutputStream](
          new ByteArrayOutputStream
        ) { (outputStream, data) =>
          outputStream.write(data)
          outputStream
        }.map { outputStream =>
          outputStream.close()
          Some(outputStream.toByteArray, fileName, contentType.get)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you do on the client side?
How the REST call looks like and how you send the file date to the server?

Comment: I don't know how you are implementing your client... but you can just test it with curl: `curl -F "image=@/path/to/your/image.jpg" http://localhost:9000/path/to/your/resource`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @j3d Hi, I am running into the same issue. Looks like that it is the solution. But don't know why it is needed to create PartHandler.Can you explain why?  I am using Play 2.4 and my client side is doing ajax file upload.

Answer (score 2):

To pass your contents, depending on your client side, you can encode the contents to Base64 at client side to pass the contents as Json (You can use Json body parser). Then on the server side you can decode the contents using a Base64 decoder (e.g. Apache Commons) to get the byte array. It will be as simple as

```
Base64.decodeBase64(YourEncodedFileContent)
```

When you have the byte array you can simply write it on disk or save it into database etc. We are using this approach in production and it works fine however we only handle small file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into BodyParsers: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaBodyParsers

What you are trying to do is not especially complicated, especially if you are only handling smaller files that would fit in memory. After all uploading a file is just about sending the file as a body of a POST or something like that. It is not any different from receiving some XML or JSON in a request.

Comment: Thanks... I already knew this document. The real question was "how should I pass the file content to the API?" I don't think encoding the whole file in the body as base-64 would be a great idea, especially if the file is large. What I'm missing is how to let the client/browser send the file chunks without a form.

Comment: So your question is more about the client side, not what Play can or can't do. I don't see why you can't just send a POST request with the file as body - without encoding it in base64 - what would be the point? Play has no problem receiving just a chunk of bytes in an action, that's actually the base behavior.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... don't need binary files to be encoded in base-64?

Answer (score 1):

> while my backend does not provide any form... it just consists of a REST API to be invoked by a JavaScript client

Then your backend is not a REST API. You should follow the HATEOAS principle, so you should respond with links and forms along with data to every GET request. You don't have to send back HTML, you can describe these things with hypermedia json or xml media types, for example with JSON-LD, HAL+JSON, ATOM+XML, etc... So you have to describe your upload form in your preferred hypermedia, and let the REST client to turn that description into a real HTML file upload form (if the client is HTML). After that you can send a `multipart/form-data` as usual (REST is media type agnostic, so you can send data in any media type you want, not just in a JSON format). Check the [AJAX file upload techniques](http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins) for further detail...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime._
import java.io.File

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content._
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import play.api.libs.ws.WS



val contents ="contents string"
val file = File.createTempFile("sample", ".txt")

val bw = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(file)
bw.write(new_contents);
bw.close();

builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create("text/plain"), "sample"))
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
val entity = builder.build

        val outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
        entity.writeTo(outputstream)
        val header = (entity.getContentType.getName -> entity.getContentType.getValue)
        val response = WS.url("/post/file").withHeaders(header).post(outputstream.toByteArray())
```